# Detecting that a user has entered a physical location with her Android / iOS device

Tags: android, ios

If a user has a particular app installed on her phone but the app is not running in the foreground, what is the best way to detect that she has entered a physical location with the Android / iOS device? Assume that the app has all the required permissions and in the case of Android, there is a background service running every minute.

I can think of polling the GPS but the drawback is that the user might have switched off her GPS.

The same would happen with a possible bluetooth wake-up if bluetooth is off. Ditto for WiFi.

Could something like supersonic sound emitted from a hardware placed at the entrance of the location work? (Something like [Tagtile](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/05/coming-soon-to-a-store-near-you-tagtile-a-square-like-mobile-loyalty-service/) perhaps?)

Which of these 4 would you most rely on? for Android? for iOS? Or would you rather use some other method?

Comment: Search for region monitoring.

Comment: If I didn't answer your full question, let me know. If you meant something else than what I answered let me know. Either way, let me know. It isn't very kind to ask someone for their help and then ignore them when they try.

Comment: Hey CaptJak, I am not ignoring you - it was a national holiday for us yesterday :) Please see my comments after your answer.

Comment: Sorry to get testy. I recently posted a bunch of answers which received no acknowledgement, and I started to go over the edge. Anyways, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to track a users whereabouts. While I will not go on to explain how the entire process is done (as it would be the equivalent of writing my own tutorial on the subject), it is gone over in detail in the Apple Docs, [covered here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497)(I believe what you are looking for is the [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126)).

This can even run in the background, as also covered in the Apple Docs in many place, [one of them being here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).

For an iOS app, that is what I would recommend.

If the user turns off Location Tracking and/or their GPS, I believe you are going to have to deal with it. Tracking a person, when they have not given permission or explicitly denied the permission to do so, is illegal in many countries.

**EDIT**

Escaping my mind for a moment was the [Google Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). Probably one of the most known and used Location services will get you your tracking for Android.

**EDIT 2**

If a person has turned off their GPS or Wifi, there would not be a way to tell their physical location. If you were able to track a person when their Wifi or GPS was turned off would classify your app as [spyware](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/08/steve-jobs-watching-you-apple-seeking-patent-0), and would not be a good idea.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to ask was that if GPS and Wifi are off, is there still a way to know if a user has entered a region / location? I think I will change the title or the question in a bit.