# Background GPS in iOS mobile safari

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps, mobile-safari

I know it is possible to have an iOS app running in the background which transmits GPS data periodically.

I was wondering if the same is possible if a user is on a webpage in mobile safari. Can watchPosition be used even if the user is not actively on the webpage but the tab is open in mobile safari (i.e. in the background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you app would have to be running in the background for it to work. You would use the same [Location Awareness API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497) that Apple provides and run it in the background, so that even when your app closes, it is still running.

You can see the answer given [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220815/2535467) for this question.

By using the instructions laid out by Apple, you can achieve this, but *your app has to be run for it to work*. So if they never start your app, no location tracking.