# Using Gamecenter can I retrieve other users score based on who is nearest?

Tags: ios, location, game-center

I want to know if it is possible to retrieve other users Game Center score based on their location. I want to display to the active user of the app only the scores from the users who are near to him. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18220815/2535467

Comment: I don't know if I am being misunderstood but what I want to know is if the game center stores the user location and can filter the users using that location. By doing this I can retrieve the users scores that are nearest to the active user.

Comment: I don't think so. Have you seen this occurring in another app?

Comment: You could probably encode this extra data in game center, however there wouldn't be an easy "Search" function.  instead you would need to look at EVERY record which I don't think is a good idea.  You could do this with your own server much more easily

Comment: No I haven't but I didn't try them all off course. I searched the web for a couple of hours and I haven't found topics on this location subject.

Comment: Yeah @portforwardpodcast that would be a possible solution. But are you saying that Game Center doesn't add the location parameter ?